# Animation in svg generates a pixel line at the border

Tags: svg

I have svg rectangles animate from bottom to top and out of the border of the svg. In some resolutions and browsers there is a pixel line building up on top. Sort of like a smear-effect.

I change colors, opacity and sizes of the svg, but the problem consists.

```
  see code in action:
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydYdpX

Comment: More information please. What browsers? What versions?

Comment: In Chrome. Latest Releases

Comment: You might need to provide more details. I tried in Win7 with Chrome 74 and 75, at various sizes. I couldn't reproduce the problem you described.